# Retrieving all data from repeater fields

Tags: php

I have a custom field in WP called `what_we_do_textarea_two`. what_we_do_textarea_two is a simple repeater field which allows you to add another item to a list.

`what_we_do_textarea_two` has a subfield called `list_item`:

[image]

Since this list may have x amount of listings, what is the best way to retrieve the data from that field? At the moment I have:

```
$textareaTwo = get_sub_field("list_item");
if ($textareaTwo && count($textareaTwo)>0){
    foreach ($textareaTwo as $textareaTwos){
        $res = get_post($textareaTwos);
        echo'Test'.$res; 
    }    
}
```

But it doesn't display anything? At the moment I have two listings in the repeater, so it should show two listings? I imagine it'll be a `for loop` since I want all data from the list the be displayed, but unsure as to why mine doesn't work?

Comment: I downvoted because there was no effort to debug the code http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/. edit your question to add more informations.

Comment: The [ACF doc has an example for the repeater field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/#usage) - why aren't you doing it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please use below code to get list item

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('what_we_do_textarea_two') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('what_we_do_textarea_two') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        the_sub_field('list_item');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>
```