# Display all custom meta field values from the database using ACF Repeater

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a personal project which includes multiple custom fields (created via ACF). A few of them are repeater types.

I want to to display 3 arrays/blocks of those repeater subfield values. For better understanding, I have this repeater field: open_workshops, and this field includes subfields: date, location, partnerships.

I want simply to show all values from those subfields stored in DB. Something like:

Open Workshops:

- Date: Jan 2017, Feb 2017...Dec 2019 etc
- Location: New York, Warsaw...
- Partnerships: EY, Google..

What issues I've noticed - first of all, because of field type (repeater) it's damn hard to find those values in the DB. Because its not a single field but ACF replicates their names, so instead of looking for single field: open_workshops_date i need somehow to find: open_workshops_0_date, open_workshops_1_date etc.

My initial code was:

```
  if( have_rows('open_workshops') ):
        while ( have_rows('open_workshops') ) : the_row();
            $sub_value_1 = get_sub_field('date');
        $sub_value_2 = get_sub_field('location');
        $sub_value_3 = get_sub_field('partnerships');


          echo '$sub_value_1';
echo '$sub_value_2';
echo '$sub_value_3';

        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
```

I've tried as well the suggestion from this post:
[Retrieving all data from repeater fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309602/retrieving-all-data-from-repeater-fields)

but it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ACF has a built-in function to do what you want.  You can use [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) to retrieve a value from any post, but it requires a post ID if you want the value from anything other than the current post.

So instead, we can query posts using [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and pass the meta key of our custom field.

Here is an example.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page', // Add your post type here
    'meta_key' => 'test_repeater' // Add your repeater name here
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($the_query->have_posts()):
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            if(have_rows('test_repeater')): // Add your repeater here
                while (have_rows('test_repeater')) : the_row(); // Add your repeater here
                    // display your sub fields
                    the_sub_field('sub_field_one');
                    the_sub_field('sub_field_two');
                endwhile;
            else :
                // no rows found
            endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

I added the above code to a page template, it will spit out the values of my `test_repeater` for any `page` that has those custom fields filled out.

Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing post id? Please see below:

```
if( have_rows('parent_field', $post_id) ):
while ( have_rows('parent_field', $post_id) ) : the_row();
    $sub_value = get_sub_field('sub_field');
    // Do something...
endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;
```

Comment: the thing is, I dont know the exact post_id. ACF stores those subfields in the db, obviously each CPT post has subfield value attached to themselves. But I dont want to display those values in CPT post. I want to show all those values in a separate/independent page (lets call it summary page). The page has nothing to do with that CPT.

Answer (score -2):

the Repeater field of ACF follows a simple method, this set of code will help you.

```
if( get_field('open_workshops', get_the_ID()) ):

$counter = 0;
while( the_repeater_field('open_workshops', get_the_ID())):

//this sets up the counter starting at 0
echo get_field('open_workshops_'.$counter.'_date', get_the_ID());
echo get_field('open_workshops_'.$counter.'_location', get_the_ID());
echo get_field('open_workshops_'.$counter.'_partnerships', get_the_ID());

$counter++; // add one per row
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Copying my previous comment (up) - the thing is, I dont know the exact post_id. ACF stores those subfields in the db, obviously each CPT post has subfield value attached to themselves. But I dont want to display those values in CPT post. I want to show all those values in a separate/independent page (lets call it summary page). The page has nothing to do with that CPT.